# DXA Java 2.2 Unable to create localization error

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2

I'm trying to use the latest DXA Java 2.2 (the latest develop branch) with Tridion 9.6 (upgraded from 8.5),

I'm able to see page query results using graphQL POST requests either from postman/curl

But when tried to request using DXA, I get **unable to create localization** error,

Further debugging shows that PublicationMapping returns the correct publication id. I've also verified the same using publicationMapping graphQL query in postman.

I'm stuck and unable to proceed here, any help would be much appreciated!

**Stack trace**:

> com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationFactoryException:
> Could not read configuration of localization for pubId:
> [publicationID] and path [/] for file [/system/config/_all.json]
>
> Caused by:
> com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.StaticContentNotFoundException: No
> binary found for pubId: [publicationID] and urlPath: https:///system/config/_all.json

Comment: @Welcome to Tridion stack exchange. it might be helpful to provide more information about the specific error message. did you try to configure the base URL in TTM? Also, run this **Sync-TTMCdenvironment** cmdlets to sync your base URLs from Topology to discovery database.

Comment: @Velmurugan I've updated the error stack trace

Comment: The error looks like it's not able to read the system/config/_all.json, did you publish the publishing settings page?